# My Meteor App keeps deleting files after rebuild

Tags: javascript, meteor, docker, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I have a meteorjs app built and deployed with mupx. however, after every deployment, I noticed that the uploaded images with the previous build are deleted and thereby resulting in broken images.

I found out that this is because of docker. WOuld have stored the images in a place outside docker but docker will not allow me (or I don't know how to do this)

My app is hosted on Ubuntu 14.04 by DigitalOcean.

How can I stop this from happening? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
First of all, When you deployed with MUPx, your app is wrapped in docker and docker deletes all files that are not in volumes after rebuild.

So, what I looked for is how to create a docker volume on deploy. This is however not possible with MUPx but MUP seems to have a way of doing this.

But I did it with MUPx by editing the start.sh file by adding this line of code  `--volume=uploads:/.uploads \`. This line means when you run `MUPx deploy`, the file will run a `docker run` to add the volume `/.uploads`.

This line makes sutr that my uploaded files are persistent.